# Can I solve Cheryls Birthday with formal logic?

Tags: logical-deduction, puzzle-theory

There is a lot of fuzz about this [Cheryls Birthday](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=cheryls+birthday) thing - and I understood the solution after a couple of deeper thoughts about it.

But what I am more interested in is; is the puzzle solvable using a form of formal logic?

During university (CS) I had many courses about formal logic and love the concept of wiriting down statements, and actually *calculating* a logical answer to it.

Is this doable with the infamous Cheryls Birthday puzzle?

Edit: Please note that I do not need an explanation of the puzzle, the solution, or how and why the participants can or can not say what they say. I am specifically looking for a solution that uses formal logic.

Comment: I don't explicitly use formal logic symbols, but this is solved using logic: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/12318/10399

Comment: Look specifically at the Epilogue in the answer I already linked you. + is AND, = is IMPLIES. If this does not satisfy you, apply your own CS training to refine it.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Sorry, I just now saw the epilogue. Must have skipped it when I skimmed the answers on the question. Looks close enough, thanks :-)

Comment: I love duplicates of duplicates of duplicates